# adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() не работает

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

У меня есть 2 активити, где в первой RecycleView показывает данные из базы данных, а во второй я добавляю новые данные в базу данных. Проблема в том, что новые данные не показываются в первой активити(только если я заново включу приложение).  notifyDataSetChanged() не помогает.

Main java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Adapter.OnAdapterListener {
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
      static Adapter adapter;
    static List<HabitInfo> habitInfoList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        habitInfoList = databaseHandler.getAllHabits();
        initRecycleView();
    }

    public  void initRecycleView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleViewMain);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new Adapter(habitInfoList, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

вторая активити:

```
public class CreateHabit extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHandler db;
    int id;
    Adapter.OnAdapterListener onAdapterListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_habit);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);


        TextView saveBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save_txt);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // DATABASE Inserting Habits
                db.addHabit(new HabitInfo("name", "desc"));

                MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Также была попытка вместо `MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` писать:

```
MainActivity.habitInfoList.clear();
                    MainActivity.habitInfoList=db.getAllHabits();
                    MainActivity.adapter=new Adapter(MainActivity.habitInfoList,  onAdapterListener );
MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: В первом случае адаптер работает со списком, который получен из базы, но с самой базой никак не связан и её обновление на список не влияет. Почему не работает второй вариант не ясно, но такое в принципе делать нельзя - вы не должны ни в коем случае трогать поля и методы другой активности. Два основных варианта: подписка - активность "слушает" изменения в базе и обновляет адаптер; [`Activity Result API`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) - запускаем активность с требованием возврата результата, в колбэке возврата обновляем адаптер

Answer (score 2):

Ваше приложение вполне может упасть, когда Вы из 2-ой активити обращаетесь к первой. Не надо так делать. По существу вопроса - нужно менять архитектуру. Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону ViewModel. Но если Вы только начинаете знакомство с андроидом, то чтобы добиться работоспособности приложения просто вынесите

```
habitInfoList = databaseHandler.getAllHabits();
initRecycleView();
```

в onResume(). Тогда `MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` из второй активити можно (и нужно) убрать.

Предупреждаю сразу, воизбежание кидания тапков - да, это далеко не лучший выход. Но работать будет (пусть и за счет времени ожидания юзера).